# Parse database - save info in table as json

Tags: c#, json, parse-platform

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 with the Parse database (https://www.parse.com/). I have a table called **app** and a field called **reviews**. In this field i want to save a json object with the following format:

```
[{"Title":"a title", "url":"a url"}, {"Title":"another title", "url":"another url"}, etc...]
```

As I have read in the documentation (https://www.parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#objects-types) Parse supports objects that implement `IDictionary<string, T>` and `IList<T>` so i have the following code:

```
var requestFormInformation = new ParseObject("app");
requestFormInformation["Reviews"] = requestForm.Reviews.ToList();
```

Reviews property is an `IEnumerable<Review>` and this is the **Review** class

```
public class Review
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

There is no error thrown when i save this code and save in the database but the item is not saved.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to place your code into a try-catch (ParseException) to see if the save fails for some reason.

Sidenote: the Parse help page suggests that you start the class name with a uppercase character and the key name with a lowercase character. "app" should be "App" and "Reviews" should be "reviews".

Another thing could be authentication or authorization. Are you properly authenticated and do you have the rights to save this object.

Comment: Saving the object does not fail. Code never goes to the catch block. I save 22 field in my code. (22th is the reviews field). When i remove the line that saves the reviews everything works fine. So it is this line that causes the error. In the Parse data browser i have defined the reviews field as Object (but this does not seem to cause a problem).

Comment: Perhaps you could breakdown the problem: remove the Url property, update the Parse.com side and try again. I'm not sure if Parse is nit-picky on casing, but your property Url will probably result in Url: in the JSON instead of url.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clear about how you want to save the data. You say you want to save it as JSON, which is a string serialization format, so the column should be of type string, and you'll have to handle JSON serialize/deserialize yourself. I don't think this is what you actually want, so forget about JSON as that is an implementation detail inside Parse.

If instead you want it to just serialize your collection you don't have to do anything special. As per the [documentation on object types](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#objects-types) you can store anything that implements IList or IDictionary including nested objects.

I would suggest you try an experiment with a simple class that has a List as one of its properties:

```
var foo = new ParseObject("Foo");
var reviews = new List<Review>();
reviews.Add(new Review { Title = "Review 1" });
reviews.Add(new Review { Title = "Review 2" });
foo["reviews"] = reviews;
await foo.SaveAsync();
```

Once that is working, test incremental changes till you find out where things have gone wrong.